# Why am I getting "ARRAY(0x145030c)" trying to write a Perl hash to a file?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash in which I store the products a customer buys (`%orders`). It uses the product code as key and has a reference to an array with the other info as value.

At the end of the program, I have to rewrite the inventory to the updated version (i.e. subtract the quantity of the bought items)

This is how I do rewrite the inventory:

```
sub rewriteInventory{
    open(FILE,'>inv.txt');
    foreach $key(%inventory){
        print FILE "$key\|$inventory{$key}[0]\|$inventory{$key}[1]\|$inventory{$key}[2]\n"
    }
    close(FILE);
}
```

where `$inventory{$key}[x]` is `0` → `Title`, `1` → `price`, `2` → `quantity`.

The problem here is that when I look at `inv.txt` afterwards, I see things like this:

```
CD-911|Lady Gaga - The Fame|15.99|21
ARRAY(0x145030c)|||
BOOK-1453|The Da Vinci Code - Dan Brown|14.75|12
ARRAY(0x145bee4)|||
```

Where do these `ARRAY(0x145030c)|||` entries come from? Or more important, how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Please I beseech you, put `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of *every* perl script or module.

Comment: My bad, was planning to do that but it brought up so many warnings etc, I just wanted to get my code finished first. I'll check using those lines after this is over :)

Comment: Your code isn't finished if it shows errors/warnings, and you might see that you've got mistaks - as this very question demonstrates.

Comment: I just noticed this gem: *This is the last part of this school task, I had so many problems programming all this, and now this stupid little thing comes up now — I'm really fed up with this whole Perl thing.* That kind of attitude is not conducive to learning. Clearly, you are not capable of programming this **simple** task. That's OK, that's why you are going to school. If it is so stupid and if you are really fed up with this whole Perl thing, feel free to go to culinary school.

Comment: I thought for sure that there was a faq answer about this, but I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I was wrong about having to use an explicit dereferencing arrow; this is inferred between brackets when necessary, even if the first brackets do NOT require a dereference. That said, I will leave the remainder of the answer as posted since it was accepted, but merely note that if you choose not to use `join`, you needn't actually use `$inventory{$key}->[0]` but can in fact use `$inventory{$key}[0]` as originally posted.

Just be aware that the first (hash) brackets do not imply a dereference but the second (array) brackets do. Your errant array refs in the output were coming from looping over not only keys but also values of the hash.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

In addition to using `keys`, you also need to dereference the references-to-array (this is why you're seeing each value output as ARRAY with an address---you're printing the references, not the values of the dereferenced array) when you print, so your loop becomes something like:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %inventory) {
    print FILE "$key\|$inventory{$key}->[0]\|$inventory{$key}->[1]\|$inventory{$key}->[2]\n";
}
```

I'd probably rewrite it a little more idiomatically as:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %inventory) {
    print FILE (join '|', $key, @{$inventory{$key}}) . "\n";
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Harm: you're welcome! Please do read my edit though, I consulted `perldoc perlref` and it turned out I was overcautious about dereferencing.

Comment: There was actually a question a few days ago about whether the extra dereferencing arrows were good style: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475042/nested-dereferencing-arrows-in-perl-to-omit-or-not-to-omit

Answer (score 4):

You want to iterate over

```
keys %inventory
```

and not

```
%inventory
```

which, as you see, causes you to iterate over key, value pairs.

Answer (score 3):

You're using your hash in list context, so you're getting all your values thrown in with your keys. I think what you actually want to do is:

```
foreach $key (keys %inventory) {
    print FILE "...";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to write that routine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %inventory;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($key, @values) = split qr{\|}, $line;
    last unless @values;
    $inventory{$key} = \@values;
}

write_inventory(\%inventory, 'test.txt');

sub write_inventory {
    my ($inventory, $output_file) = @_;

    open my $output, '>', $output_file
        or die "Cannot open '$output_file': $!";

    for my $item ( keys %$inventory ) {
        unless ( 'ARRAY' eq ref $inventory{$item} ) {
            warn "Invalid item '$item' in inventory\n";
            next;
        }

        print $output join('|', $item, @{ $inventory{$item} }), "\n";
    }

    close $output
        or die "Cannot close '$output': $!";
}
__DATA__
CD-911|Lady Gaga - The Fame|15.99|21
BOOK-1453|The Da Vinci Code - Dan Brown|14.75|12
```

#### The rules are:

- Don't use global variables: Pass a reference to `%inventory` to `write_inventory` instead of having it operate on the global `%inventory`.
- Don't use global variables: Instead of using the bareword file handle `FILE` which has package scope, use a lexical file handle whose scope is limited to `write_inventory`.
- Check for errors on file operations: Make sure `open` succeeded before plowing ahead and trying to write. Make sure `close` succeeded before assuming all data you printed actually got saved.
- You ***MUST*** use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) because, at this point in your learning process, you do not know enough to know what you do not know.o