# How to print an $element of an @array that is used as a value of %hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I think this should be easy to solve for experienced people, for me though I was trying and searched on google about this but couldnt find anything that fits my situation. I just want to let $amountok and $amountko give out the values they have at index 0 and 1 but it is not working like this (see # marks).

```
print ERGEBNIS "ID;Amount;Amount OK;Amount KO\n";
foreach my $key (keys %elementhash){
  my $sum = 0;              
  foreach $valueofkey(@{$elementhash{$key}}){                   
     $sum += $valueofkey;           
  }

  #my $amountok= @{$elementhash{$key}[0]};
  #my $amountko= @{$elementhash{$key}[1]};

  print ERGEBNIS $key.";".$sum.";".$amountok.";".$amountko."\n";

}
```

this would give me out the error: "Cant use string "7" as an array ref.", this must be possible somehow but i just don't know how! thank you guys

this is the Dumper output of %elementhash:

```
 $VAR1 = {                '1000' => [7],               
                          '2000' => [5],                  
                          '3000' => [56, 12]              
         };
```

Comment: What does `%elementhash` contain?

Comment: You're also missing a `my` for `$valueofkey`.

Comment: Write `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%elementhash` before first `foreach` loop and share the output.

Comment: thanks, I have added the dumper output to OP

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to dereference the first and second items in the array. Try something like `$elementhash{$key}[0]`

Comment: tried that already @yonyon100 , it gives me an uninitialized value error

Comment: Try:  @{$elementhash{$key}}[0]; because @{$elementhash{$key}} is the value and this is an Array. and @{$elementhash{$key}}[0] is the value of the Array on the first index

Comment: I don't know, but it worked for me. That's the output I got: `3000;68;56;12
1000;7;7;
2000;5;5;`

Comment: Word of advice: don't mix German identifiers in your code. Either go English or German, but don't mix. It will be confusing later. Also don't name variables by their type. Name them by what they represent. `$valueofkey` could be `$amount` for example.

Comment: @simbabque usually i write the code so I can fully understand it (also using easier-to-read variable names for myself) afterwards when everything is working I replace them so others are also able to understand and work with the code. Actually for me it was easier to think of $valueofkey than of $amount, because I personally still struggle a bit when it comes down to more complex structures like arrays as hash keys. yes, i am a bloody noob :P

Comment: The array _reference_ is the hash **value** here, not the hash key. It can't be a key. If you use an array as a hash key, it will be forced into scalar context and thus will return the number of elements. `perl -MData::Dumper -e'@foo = (5,7); $bar{@foo} = 1; print Dumper \%bar'`. If you use an array reference as a hash key, you'll get the string for the address like `HASH(0xD34DB33F)`. `perl -MData::Dumper -e'$foo = [5,7]; $bar{$foo} = 1; print Dumper \%bar'`. But don't worry, you'll figure this stuff out after a while ;)

Comment: Think of a hash like a table with two columns. A key-value-pair is one line. That's like `$foo{bar} = 1`. If you want all the [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html), you get the left column. If you want all the [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html), you get the right column.

Comment: thats exactly how I explained it to myself (even draw it). Now I know what you meant by that post before, yes, the @array is the value of the hash, not the key. the key is "1000" as example in my code!! thank you, just another mistake that happened because of not being a native speaker.. :P

Comment: You speak German, right? There are perlmonger user groups in most larger cities in Germany. If you happen to be in the Berlin area you should come by and we will explain it in German. :-)

Comment: You are german too? Didnt expect that. Unfortunately I live in Köln, I will try to find a group nearby

Comment: There is Cologne, Duesseldorf and Niederrhein.pm. The latter is very active and often sees Dutch people join as well. You're close enough to try AmsterdamX.pm too. That's the Amsterdam expatriates community. They have a lot of very interesting people there. Check my profile here to learn more about the Perl community in Germany. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hash *elements* contain array references. Even if there is only one value in the array ref, it's still an array ref. You *can* use the `->` operator for dereferencing.

```
$elementhash{$key}->[0];
```

Note that you first have a hash, not a hash reference, so there is no arrow before the `{$key}` part. Inside there is an array reference. In fact, you don't strictly need to put a `->` in front of the `[0]` because Perl knows that nested data structures are built from references. It's a matter of preference that's [been well discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2475042/1331451). I personally like the arrow, but it's not needed here<sup>1</sup>.

What you tried to do with `@{$elementhash{$key}[0]}` was take the first element inside the `$key`, e. g. the `7` for key `1000`, and deref that as an array. Of course you can't do that, because it's a number, and not an array reference.

Because not all of the arrays in your data structure have two values, you should check if the second value exists. You can do that with the `//` defined-or operator. It allows `0` or other un-true values, but not `undef`.

Finally, you were missing a `my` for `$valueofkey`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %elementhash = (
    '1000' => [7],
    '2000' => [5],
    '3000' => [ 56, 12 ]
);

print "ID;Amount;Amount OK;Amount KO\n";
foreach my $key ( keys %elementhash ) {
    my $sum = 0;
    foreach my $valueofkey ( @{ $elementhash{$key} } ) {
        $sum += $valueofkey;
    }

    my $amountok = $elementhash{$key}->[0];
    my $amountko = $elementhash{$key}->[1] // 0;

    print $key. ";" . $sum . ";" . $amountok . ";" . $amountko . "\n";
}
```

---

Note that you can rewrite the last line to use `join`.

```
print join( ';', $key, $sum, $amountok, $amountko ),  "\n";
```

If your Perl is at least version 5.10, you can also turn on `use feature 'say'` so you don't need to print the `"\n"`.

```
say join ';', $key, $sum, $amountok, $amountko;
```

If you have more complicated CSV, consider using [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV) or [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) instead.

---

<sup>1) You **do need one arrow** if the variable that you are starting from is a reference. But you *can* omit the following ones.</sup>

```
my $foo = { bar => [1, 2, 3] };
say $foo->{bar}[2]; # works
say $foo{bar}[2]; # complains that %foo needs explicit package name
```

Comment: worked! thanks for the explanation! i had $valueofkey defined at the start of the code. Also thanks for the `say` tip, didnt know it would do this. I will later convert my .csv file to a .xls file with csv_xs, so its fine! :)

Comment: @ZesaRex don't do that. Always use the smallest possible scope for any variables. Especially loop iterators should always be lexical to their loop.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak sorry about that. :P

Comment: @simbabque okay, will try to do so in next projects!

Comment: @ZesaRex: Or you could edit your current project to use the good advice you have been given :-)

Comment: Arrows between braces are *never* required.  Ever.  `$foo[0]->{bar}` is 100% equivalent to `$foo[0]{bar}`.

Comment: @paul yes. But it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Then your answer should reflect that.  Instead, the first two paragraphs of your answer are incorrectly telling the OP that he "needs" to use the arrow syntax.  These two paragraphs should be removed from the answer, as they are incorrect and irrelevant.

Comment: @PaulL the first paragraph said you _can_ use one. The second paragraph indeed said you need it, because I'm firmly on the side that puts arrows everywhere in that discussion. I don't think either way is wrong. I've updated the answer to include an explanation of what is optional when. I chose not to remove those paragraphs but rather rewrite them with more explanations, because I believe for a beginner the arrows are helpful to understand deeply nested data structures.